# Recommended way to POST and receive from web service, all from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to send some data to a web service using a form with POST method, to which it responds with an XML page.  I have the POST part working with a simple form and submit in my View.  However, I am not sure how to handle the response from here, so I am trying to move it all into the controller (seems like it should be there anyway).  So the theory is to have the user click a button which sends model data to the controller.  In the controller i am trying to put together a webrequest, looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitToCris(NewApplicantViewModel model)
    {
        string serviceURL = "https://www.blahblah.com/XMLServer/XMLServer.cgi";

        string postData = "MaxRecords=0&UserID=skapi&Password=sk12024&Version=2.0&RequestType=searchName&FirstName=Nathan"
                                    + "&LastName=Smith&DOB=1984/2/2";

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(serviceURL);
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        return View();

    }
```

I don't seem to be getting a response so I dug in an found a "stream does not support seek operations".  Looks like this is caused by an inability read the length of the byte array.  I will fix it by looping through.

So what I am looking for right now is, is this even the correct way to go?  I have been researching this all morning and have come up with multiple ways of doing this, I went with this one because it seemed the most direct approach.

Anywho, if I could get an MVC or ASP specific example or tutorial on how this is all supposed to work, that would be great. Thanks.

-------EDIT-------------

Changed the postData variable.

Here is the response I receive from the other companies web server after posting the data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <HistoryResponse>
  <ResponseType>resultsList</ResponseType>
  <Matches>0</Matches>
  <SessionID>75803234r23df3de</SessionID>
  <RecStart>0</RecStart>
  <ClientCode></ClientCode>
  <Results></Results>
</HistoryResponse>
```

Comment: First that is not how you build post data.  That is how you might build a browser form that would create post data.  Post data is specially formatted and submitted as a stream to a webrequest.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/debx8sh9(v=vs.100).aspx .  Are you wanting to post to a remote service and retreive back an XML file that you will then process and show the user some input based on that?

Comment: Bryan - Thank you, I will look at that shortly.  Yes I need to send the data to the web server of a company, then they respond with a short XML reponse (I have added an example of the response to my post).  I need to grab the sessionid and matches values, save them to variables for later use.

Comment: Here is a dated but straight forward sample that builds post data formatted in name/value pairs like you would want http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I spent a couple days researching and asking around, about how to post some data from an MVC controller, then grab the XML response.  I was surprised to find no answers on the net and  I can only assume my search parameters were faulty, because it does not seem to be such an esoteric thing.  Anywho, I thought I would post my working code, on the off chance it can be useful to someone.  Disclaimer - I just started coding a few months ago, so even though this works, I don't guaranty it is the best way to do it. :-)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitToCris(NewApplicantViewModel model)
    {
        // Setup my variables
        string First = model.PersonModel.FirstName;
        string Last = model.PersonModel.LastName;
        string dob = model.PersonModel.DateofBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        string historyURL = "https://www.nunya.com/XMLServer/XMLServer.cgi";
        //Build my data to be sent in key/value pair string 
        string postData = "MaxRecords=0&UserID=skapi&Password=sk12024&Version=2.0&RequestType=searchName&FirstName="
                                    + First + "&LastName="
                                    + Last + "&DOB="
                                    + dob;

        //Create the web request, populate the header info
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(crisURL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        // Send it
        using (Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            writeStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            writeStream.Close();
        }

        // Receive the response and do stuff with it.
        string result = string.Empty;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using( Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream() )
            {
                using( StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }

            }
        }

        XDocument resultLoad = XDocument.Parse(result);
        ViewBag.XmlResponse = resultLoad.ToString();

        return View();

    }
```

At this time, I am not doing much with the response and it is nothing more than a string.  I personally need to store some of the info and format a couple views, depending on the returned data.  Once I get that sorted, I will post it, but I wanted to get this out there now.